# Mocking static class in Mockito

Tags: mockito, static-methods, powermockito

I have something like the following:

```
    public class Foo {

    public static String getValue(String key) {
        return key + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Now I need to have a test case for it and here is how I attempted:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
   PowerMockito.mockStatic(Foo.class);
    PowerMockito.when(Foo.getValue("123")).thenReturn("abcd");
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();

}
```

When I run the test case, I get this:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:495)
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you confirm that you've added a `@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)` annotation onto your test class as listed [on the PowerMock site](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#mocking-static-method), and that you're using the [PowerMockRunner](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/master/modules/module-impl/junit4/src/main/java/org/powermock/modules/junit4/PowerMockRunner.java) JUnit4 runner?

Static methods are invoked with static dispatch, not dynamic dispatch using Java's normal polymorphism and method overrides. To replace the implementation, PowerMock needs to load a replacement class before the test starts running, and the runner and annotation make that happen.

Comment: You are right. I added the PrepareForTest annotation and it worked.